# Add javascript in php code and php code in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to get the info from a PHP variable in to JavaScript while in the PHP `if` statement. I am not sure what is wrong. I tried to escape the PHP code then I thought I cannot have PHP code tags with in PHP code.

**Here is my code but this does not work:**

```php
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
if ($user->guest) 
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push([\'_setCustomVar\',1,\'User_Status\',\'Guest\',1])</script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push([\'_setCustomVar\',2,\'UserID\',\'GuestUser\',1])</script>';
} else {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push([\'_setCustomVar\',1,\'User_Status\',\'LoggedIn\',1])</script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push([\'_setCustomVar\',2,\'UserID\',\' "echo $user->id "\', 1])</script>';
}
```

Can you please help?
Many Thanks
Jai

Comment: Are you sure with this statement `$user =& JFactory::getUser();`, shouldn't this be `$user = &JFactory::getUser();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push([\'_setCustomVar\',2,\'UserID\',\''.$user->id.'\', 1])</script>';
```

I guess... no echo inside of echo and connect string via `.`

You also might to try out the following:

```
<?php 
   $user =& JFactory::getUser();
   if ($user->guest) {
   ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'User_Status','Guest',1])</script>
      <script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',2,'UserID','GuestUser',1])</script>
   <?php
   } else {
   ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'User_Status','LoggedIn',1])</script>
      <script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',2,'UserID','<?=$user->id?>', 1])</script>   
   <?php
   }
   ?>
```

This might be easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are breaking your string! In this cases I usually take the part of string that is between this quotes and put it in a variable. For example $setcustomvar="'_setCustomVar\'" and then you add it in your echo code like this:

```
'<script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push([\'.$setcustomvar.'
```

etc..

and like the others are saying you can't put an echo inside a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access php variable like that in last echo, to get user->id dynamicly use this

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push([\'_setCustomVar\',2,\'UserID\',\' '.$user->id.' "\', 1])</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript code is regarded as string in php. Just concatenate your variable value with the string and it will work.

Try this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push([\'_setCustomVar\',2,\'UserID\',\'' . $user->id . '\', 1])</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push([\'_setCustomVar\',2,\'UserID\',\' "echo $user->id "\', 1])</script>';
```

Try this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push([\'_setCustomVar\',2,\'UserID\',\' ' . $user->id . '\', 1])</script>';
```

Can can't nest `echo`'s. You'll have to use string concatenation, instead.

However, for full efficiency, I'd suggest this:

```
<?php
    $user =& JFactory::getUser();
    $userStatus = 'LoggedIn';  // Set default values first.
    $userId = $user->id;
    if ($user->guest) {
        $userStatus = 'Guest'; // Override defaults if the user is a guest.
        $userId = 'GuestUser';
    }
?>
<script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'User_Status','<?=$userStatus  ?>',1])</script>
<script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',2,'UserID','<?=$userId ?>',1])</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this will work:

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
if ($user->guest) 
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push([\""_setCustomVar"\",1,\""User_Status"\",\""Guest"\",1])</script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push([\""_setCustomVar"\",2,\""UserID"\",\""GuestUser"\",1])</script>';
} else {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push([\""_setCustomVar"\",1,\""User_Status"\",\""LoggedIn"\",1])</script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push([\""_setCustomVar"\",2,\""UserID"\",\"" $user->id "\", 1])</script>';
}
```

You don't need to give **echo $user_id** inside the php echo. just **$user_id** will work

Comment: This won't work since the string's delimited by `'` instead of `"`. PHP won't try to parse variables in single-quote strings.

Comment: what if the single quote is replaced with double ?

Comment: Assuming you escape nested quotes properly, that will work for simple variables. I don't know if it works for things like `$user->id`

Comment: when i run the code i get values like this <script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push([\""_setCustomVar"\",1,\""User_Status"\",\""Guest"\",1])</script><script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push([\""_setCustomVar"\",2,\""UserID"\",\""GuestUser"\",1])</script>

Comment: and when user i logged in the php variable does not get updated i get values like this <script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push([\""_setCustomVar"\",1,\""User_Status"\",\""LoggedIn"\",1])</script><script type="text/javascript">_gaq.push([\""_setCustomVar"\",2,\""UserID"\",\"" $user->id "\", 1])</script>